# Two dimensional dataframe cannot be displayed via DT::datatable() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Im trying to display a dataframe that I process as datatable in a `shiny` app but I get:

```
Error in datatable("dt") : 
  'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)

## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(tibble)

initial<-structure(list(case_id = c("3397364", "3397364"), action = c("3397364-RAAMELK", 
                                                                      "3397364-RAAMELK"), resource = c("RAAMELK", "RAAMELK"), lifecycle = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                            1), registration_type = structure(1:2, .Label = c("start", "complete"
                                                                                                                                            ), class = "factor"), timestamp = structure(c(1667523600, 1667531220
                                                                                                                                            ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), activity = c("RAAMELK", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            "RAAMELK"), activity_description = c("Forbrukt r<e5>melk", "Forbrukt r<e5>melk"
                                                                                                                                                                                                            ), ...9 = c(NA, NA), product = c("K101152", "K101152"), product_type_text = c("200100 - Milk", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "200100 - Milk"), qty = c(NA, 31), in_out = c("in", "out"), qty_scrap = c(NA_real_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    NA_real_), `FP ordre` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), Artikkeltype = c("SF", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "SF"), .order = 1:2), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("eventlog", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "log", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), case_id = "case_id", activity_id = "activity", activity_instance_id = "action", lifecycle_id = "registration_type", resource_id = "resource", timestamp = "timestamp")
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      datatable("dt")
      #selectInput("cols","Select column to convert",choices = colnames(initial),multiple = F,selected =colnames(initial)[1] ),
      #actionButton("conv","Convert to numeric")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) { # add session so we can update
    output$dt<-renderDataTable({
      
      dat<-data.frame(tibble(Name = colnames(initial), Class = sapply(initial, function(x) 
        paste(class(x), collapse=", "))))
      
      
      datatable(dat)
    }) 
    
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `datatable` function instead of the `dataTableOutput` function for within the as per the `ui` Shiny function [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html). The DT [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) is always a good source as well if you are working with tables.

In addition, you do not need to wrap your dataframe `dt` with the `datatable` function in the `server` function. You can just return the dataframe as a tibble or as a dataframe at the end of the `renderTable` function.

I tidyed up your code, added the necessary R packages at the top for others to test, and implemented the fix that I mentioned just above.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse) # for the tibble

# Tidy version of the reprex table
initial <- structure(
  list(
    case_id = c("3397364", "3397364"),
    action = c(
      "3397364-RAAMELK",
      "3397364-RAAMELK"
    ),
    resource = c("RAAMELK", "RAAMELK"),
    lifecycle = c(1, 1),
    registration_type = structure(
      1:2,
      .Label = c("start", "complete"), class = "factor"
    ),
    timestamp = structure(c(1667523600, 1667531220),
      tzone = "UTC",
      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
    ),
    activity = c(
      "RAAMELK",
      "RAAMELK"
    ),
    activity_description = c("Forbrukt r<e5>melk", "Forbrukt r<e5>melk"), ...9 = c(NA, NA), product = c("K101152", "K101152"), product_type_text = c(
      "200100 - Milk",
      "200100 - Milk"
    ),
    qty = c(NA, 31),
    in_out = c("in", "out"),
    qty_scrap = c(NA_real_, NA_real_),
    `FP ordre` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_),
    Artikkeltype = c("SF", "SF"),
    .order = 1:2
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c(
    "eventlog",
    "log", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
  ),
  case_id = "case_id",
  activity_id = "activity",
  activity_instance_id = "action",
  lifecycle_id = "registration_type",
  resource_id = "resource",
  timestamp = "timestamp"
)



shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage( # I used the fluidPage here for simplicity
      dataTableOutput("dt")
      #selectInput("cols","Select column to convert",choices = colnames(initial),multiple = F,selected =colnames(initial)[1] ),
      #actionButton("conv","Convert to numeric")
    )
  ,
  server = function(input, output, session) { # add session so we can update
    output$dt<-renderDataTable({
      tibble(
        Name = colnames(initial),
        Class = sapply(initial, function(x) {
          paste(class(x), collapse = ", ")
        })
      )
      # datatable(dat) # this step was causing you trouble, and can be dropped
    }) 
    
  }
)
```

Hope that helps,